# Rails db: seed issue. I am receiving a strange error regarding the seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Error**

```
‍♀️ Seeding powers...
‍♀️ Seeding heroes...
‍♀️ Adding powers to heroes...
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Power without an ID
/Users/nd/Desktop/code-practice/db/seeds.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/nd/Desktop/code-practice/db/seeds.rb:31:in `times'
/Users/nd/Desktop/code-practice/db/seeds.rb:31:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/nd/Desktop/code-practice/db/seeds.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**seed file**

```
Hero.destroy_all 
HeroPower.destroy_all

puts "‍♀️ Seeding powers..."
Power.create([
  { name: "super strength", description: "gives the wielder super-human strengths" },
  { name: "flight", description: "gives the wielder the ability to fly through the skies at supersonic speed" },
  { name: "super human senses", description: "allows the wielder to use her senses at a super-human level" },
  { name: "elasticity", description: "can stretch the human body to extreme lengths" }
])

puts "‍♀️ Seeding heroes..."
Hero.create([
  { name: "Kamala Khan", super_name: "Ms. Marvel" },
  { name: "Doreen Green", super_name: "Squirrel Girl" },
  { name: "Gwen Stacy", super_name: "Spider-Gwen" },
  { name: "Janet Van Dyne", super_name: "The Wasp" },
  { name: "Wanda Maximoff", super_name: "Scarlet Witch" },
  { name: "Carol Danvers", super_name: "Captain Marvel" },
  { name: "Jean Grey", super_name: "Dark Phoenix" },
  { name: "Ororo Munroe", super_name: "Storm" },
  { name: "Kitty Pryde", super_name: "Shadowcat" },
  { name: "Elektra Natchios", super_name: "Elektra" }
])

puts "‍♀️ Adding powers to heroes..."

strengths = ["Strong", "Weak", "Average"]
Hero.all.each do |hero|
  rand(1..3).times do
    # get a random power
    power = Power.find(Power.pluck(:id).sample)

    HeroPower.create!(hero_id: Hero.first.id, power_id: Power.first.id, strength: strengths.sample)
  end
end

puts "‍♀️ creating hero powers for heroes..."
HeroPower.create!(hero_id: Hero.all.sample, power_id: Power.all.sample, strength: strengths.all.sample)
# HeroPower.create!(hero_id: , power_id: Power.first.id, strength: strengths.sample)

puts "‍♀️ Done seeding!"
```

**schema file**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_10_22_025009) do

  create_table "hero_powers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "strength"
    t.integer "hero_id"
    t.integer "power_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "heroes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "super_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "powers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

**Power model**

```
class Power < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :hero_powers
    has_many :heroes, through: :hero_powers

    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
end
```

**My Steps and Concerns**

1. created migrations & models
2. established model relationships
3. created controllers
4. configured seed file and routes
5. ran rails db:migrate, db:seed - all successfully no errors persisted
6. added controller actions for all 3 models
7. Tested routes in localhost:3000 and noticed powers json data not rendered
8. rails c > Power.all

**Result**

```
irb(main):001:0> Power.all
   (2.2ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  Power Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "powers".* FROM "powers" /* loading for inspect */ LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

At this point I understand that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Power without an ID` unfortunately I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add Power model file, there may be a validation rule which is not passing. like maximum/minimum length.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, length: { minimum: 2 }
  validates :bio, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }
  validates :registration_number, length: { is: 6 }
end
```

you may debug these methods at `rails console`, with rails console you can see the logs.

with Power model validations, it seems your Power model instances descriptions have more than 20 string lengths. You can remove length: { maximum: 20 } from validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 } or raise the limit of maximum, like length: { maximum: 250 }, or you can use shorter descriptions at your seed data.

e.g
`validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 }`

Comment: I have a Power model. posted it above.

Comment: I updated my answer.